# How does Api.ai Google dialogueflow classifies "intent" and extracts data from slots

Tags: nlp, text-mining, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to build a very naive version of Api.ai, now Google DailogueFlow. 
I wanted to know two things.

1. How DF classifies sentences with entities in it that can be user created and/or things like date, place, time, currency or even random text (which they call 'system.any')
2. How data is extracted from slots after user map the slots with the sentence.

What algorithm/libraries and techniques do they use to classify, extract and identify user queries.

Comment: use Rasa NLU, it's open source and you can see all the tricks https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/

Comment: I am also looking for some detailed answer for this one. Would be nice if someone who is experienced in Dialogflow (api.ai) jumps in.